# $.getJSON is not retrieving file

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I have the following script whose ultimate purpose will be to fetch a local JSON file and populate a list with its contents. The problem is the file is never retrieved, but instead the fail function is called, and, bafflingly, the argument to the function contains the contents of the JSON file as 'responseText'. What gives?

In the worst case scenario, I could just turn the responseText into a JSON object and then use that to populate my list, but I'd rather figure out why this isn't working the way it's supposed to.

```
$( function() {
$.getJSON("public/data/opps.json", function(data) {
    console.log(data); // Never executes
})
  .fail(function(msg) {
      console.log(msg['responseText']); // Prints the contents of opps.json as a string
  });
});
```

Comment: Just for clarification. You're saying that the fail function is correctly returning the contents of the file? Have you checked the network? Maybe you're returning an incorrect mime type and you're not getting a 200, but you're still getting the content. Also please show the contents of opp.json.

Comment: There was a syntax error in the JSON file. That's why it was being returned as a string in the fail function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that opps.json is not a valid JSON file.

When I tried your code and ensured the contents were JSON, it worked.  For instance, if opps.json is:

```
[1,2,3]
```

Everything works as expected.  however, if it's something like:

```
xyz
```

Then it fails.

Also, put a different message in your .fail (eg: console.log('FAIL')) to make sure the failure shows up, so you can see what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's very likely that your JSON file is not valid, e.g. there are syntax errors. This was mentioned in [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), too:

> Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error,
>   the request will usually fail silently. Avoid frequent hand-editing of
>   JSON data for this reason. JSON is a data-interchange format with
>   syntax rules that are stricter than those of JavaScript's object
>   literal notation. For example, all strings represented in JSON,
>   whether they are properties or values, must be enclosed in
>   double-quotes. For details on the JSON format, see http://json.org/.

**In short**, jQuery will try to parse the JSON retrieved using the [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/). If it fails, then it would pass the invalid JSON to the `fail` handler, not the `success` handler.